# How to display data in MdiChild forms received from serialport

Tags: c#

Sir, 
I created a MDI Parent form and three Mdi Child forms. Each child form contains a button. on clicking the button a new form is displayed. Mean to say if I click all the 3 buttons in 3 child form then there will be 3 new forms displayed. Its Fine.

My problems are :

1- Each new form which is displayed on clicking the button is also shown in the taskbar. I want each new form(apart from mdi child form) to be the mdi child of the main mdi parent.

2- These new forms diaplay the data received from the device connected via serialport. How many serialport objects I must create? If one, then where it must be created, on the Main mdi parent form or on the individual forms(3 new forms) ? If it is on the MDI parent form then how can i access that object in the 3 newly opened forms? If it is on the newly created forms then there would be 3 serialport objects accessing the same COM port which will result an Exception stating- "COM port is not accessible".

PLease reply... I am recently passed out graduate and new in c#. SO please reply so that i can undrstand properly.
Thanks....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Every new Form has a bool property ShowInTaskbar - set it to false

```
// Create new MDI Child
// within ButtonClick in MainForm
CHILDFORMCLASS nf = new CHILDFORMCLASS();
nf.mdiParent = this;
nf.Show();
```

2) SerialPort Object - I would only create one in the main form
    In your ChildForms you may access the mainForm by using MdiParent

```
MainForm
     Write a public property to access the serialPort

ChildForm
     PARENTFORMCLASS p = (PARENTFORMCLASS) this.Mdiparent;
     p.PUBLICPROPERTY // to access serial port object
```

3) as there is only one object - should no longer occur

hth

Comment: 1- This is true for creating child form. but clicking a button on the chihld form opens a new form. I want that form to be the child. If i use---  Form1 newform=new Form1(); newform.MdiParent=mdichild; Then It gives an exception that Mdichild form cant not treat as parent and child both.

Comment: for 2- Where to write Serialport.Open(); If it is in the constructor of the main parent form then each time a new object is created, it will raise an exception for COM port accessing.

Comment: 1) If you create a new childForm within a childForm try this: Form1 newForm = new Form1(); newForm.MdiParent = this.mdiParent; 2) I'll check this right afer I had some coffee :D

Comment: Did you set all necessary arguments? (PortName, BaudRate, Parity, DataBit, StopBits, Handshake, ReadTimeout, WriteTimeout) - what kind of exception do you get? InvalidOperation, ArgumentOutofRange, Argument, IO .... you may check MSDN SerialPort.Open() for this - please give more detailed information

Answer (score 1):

1) When showing the form, set the MdiParent property:

```
newform.MdiParent = mdiparent;
newform.Show();
```

2) you create as many SerialPort objects as you have serial ports open.
   If there is one, I'd open it on the parent which then sends the data to the children via a method call (you could be clever and give them all one interface :).
   It is then in full control of parsing the data and filtering what each receives.

Comment: newform.MdiParent = mdiparent; how can I access mdiparent object on the newly created form.

Comment: It is normally set by whatever creates the object/window. If ont he main form, pass "this", if on an already child window, it will have it as "this.mdiParent".